# dropdown list value is not assigning in jquery

Tags: jquery

i am trying to post the form elements using jquery
i am not able to assign value which is present in the dropdown box rest of the text field values are working fine.
jquery code is shown below

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
             function ValComp(){

               $.post('valcomp.php', { CardNo: compform.CardNo.value,
               Reason: conform.Reason.value,
                   Fir: compform.Fir.value },
               function(output){
                 $('#comp').html(output).show();
                 });
             }

    </script>
```

and code for the drop down menu is

```
<select name="Reason" >
                        <option value="L">Lost</option>
                        <option value="S">Stolen</option>
                        <option value="D">Damage</option>
                    </select></td>
```

Comment: You have typo in the form name: `conform` instead of `compform`. Anyway that's bad practice, use jQuery to read the values.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('select[name=Reason]').val()
```

is the value of the selected option

Comment: $.post('valcomp.php', { CardNo: compform.CardNo.value,Reason:$('select[name=Reason]').val(),Fir: compform.Fir.value },
               function(output){
                 $('#comp').html(output).show();
                 })

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `<select>` elements have a built-in `value` property (at least, not one that works in all browsers). To get the value of a select element use the jQuery `.val()` method. So:

```
$('select[name="Reason"]').val()

// instead of

conform.Reason.value
```

Or in the context of your code:

```
$.post('valcomp.php',
       { CardNo: compform.CardNo.value,
         Reason: $('select[name="Reason"]').val(),
         Fir: compform.Fir.value },
       function(output){
          $('#comp').html(output).show();
       });
```